# Becker Robots: Getting them to move

Tags: java, karel

So I have to use the becker.robots package to move forward and pick up a certain amount of flashers and then turn around and place them. However, I am not sure how to invoke the robot.move() method. Everytime I try to make it move forward I get a compiler error saying :

Error: method move in class becker.robots.Robot cannot be applied to given types;
  required: no arguments
  found: int
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Could someone please help me :)

Comment: Can you provide code that you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving a robot in Karel/Becker can only move a single step at a time. By design, of course.

[From the documentation](http://www.learningwithrobots.com/doc/becker/robots/Robot.html#move%28%29).

If you wish to move 6 spaces forward, you will need to do a for loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    robot.move();
}
```

Or call robot.move() 6 times:

```
    robot.move();
    robot.move();
    robot.move();
    robot.move();
    robot.move();
    robot.move();
```

Alternatively, can create a method to move it multiple times.

```
void customMove(int move) {
    for(int i = 0; i < move; i++) {
        robot.move();
    }
}
```

Then a call of `customMove(6);` will move Karel forwards 6 times.

Obviously, to avoid breaking Karel, you should check if it's clear before moving, but this is a conceptual design for movement.

Answer (score 0):

- required: no arguments
- found: int

you're writing `robot.move(5)` or something else that resolves into a number, you're supposed to write `robot.move()`. Use for example a loop if you want to move 5 times.